# Pass a java array to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, arrays

In my app I have an array and I want to pass this array to a javascript script to display an html list.
My app generate this array after reading information from JSON and I need to pass it to javascript. In iOS I used this function: `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.
How I can do the same in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gson library. It is an amazing JSON parsing library that can parse and create JSON arrays.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

So convert your array to JSON and send it over :)